# How to handle error in Program.cs in asp.net core web app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a multitenant application that I'm restricting access to specific tenants. The code to authorize a user from specific tenants works fine and for those without access I'm throwing a SecurityTokenInvalidIssuerException. The problem is I don't know how to capture this error because the code is executed at the start of Program.cs and prior to the app.build. How do I gracefully handle this error? ...right now it's just crashing the app.

**Program.cs**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
//builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
//    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(builder.Configuration);

// Restrict users to specific belonging to specific tenants
UserValidator user = new UserValidator();
builder.Services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters.IssuerValidator = user.ValidateSpecificIssuers;
});
```

**UserValidator.cs**

```
public class UserValidator
{
    public string ValidateSpecificIssuers(string issuer, SecurityToken securityToken,
                                          TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
    {
        var validIssuers = GetAcceptedTenantIds()
                             .Select(tid => $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tid}/v2.0");
        if (validIssuers.Contains(issuer))
        {
            return issuer;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new SecurityTokenInvalidIssuerException("The sign-in user's account does not belong to one of the tenants that this Web App accepts users from.");
        }
    }
    private string[] GetAcceptedTenantIds()
    {
        // If you are an ISV who wants to make the Web app available only to certain customers who
        // are paying for the service, you might want to fetch this list of accepted tenant ids from
        // a database.
        // Here for simplicity we just return a hard-coded list of TenantIds.
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();

        var acceptedTenants = config.GetSection("Tenants").GetChildren();
        string[] tenants = new string[acceptedTenants.Count()];
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var acceptedTenant in acceptedTenants)
        {
            tenants[i] = acceptedTenant.GetValue<string>("TenantId");
        i++;
        }

        return tenants;
    }
}
```

Comment: Experiencing the same issue, how did you solve the above one?

Comment: @CeesJanNolen I never did. It's not really a high priority issue for me, so it's still unresolved.